# How can i add an attribute into a variable in c# xml serialization?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am new to XML serialization in C#. I want to serialize my `Dependency` object instance so that it looks like this:

```xml
<Dependency Software="Some software">some value</Dependency>
```

I tried this:

```cs
public class Dependency{
    [XmlAttribute("Software")]
    public string soft;
    public string value;
}
```

However, the output looks like the below which is not what I want:

```xml
<Dependency Software="Some Software">
 <value>some value</value>
</Dependency>
```

Is there any way to achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A public property's value will appear in an element with the property name if you do not tell the serializer otherwise.

To get the output you want, you need to decorate it with the `XmlText` attribute, for example:

```
public class Dependency
{
    [XmlAttribute("Software")]
    public string soft;
    [XmlText]
    public string value;
}
```

The property value will then appear as the value of the parent class element - `Dependency` in this case.